# Error al enviar un formulario

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo este error que dice que una condicion inesperado no deja completar la transaccion :mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2017 (HY000): Can't open named pipe to host: . pipe: MySQL (2)
pueden notar algo mal en mi codigo?
", line 14, in register
db, c =get_db()
, line 8, in get_db
g.db= mysql.connector.connect(`
al enviar un formulario

```
    def get_db():
    if "db" not in g:
        g.db= mysql.connector.connect(
            host=current_app.config["DATABASE_HOST"],
            user=current_app.config["DATABASE_USER"],
            password=current_app.config["DATABASE_PASSWORD"],
            database=current_app.config["DATABASE"]
        )
        g.c=g.db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    return g.db, g.c
esta es la fundcion de registro el error en la linea 14:

    @bp.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method =="POST":
        username=request.form["username"]
        password=request.form["password"]
        db, c =get_db()
        error=None
        c.execute(
            "select id from user where username= %s", (username,)
        )
        if not username:
            error="Username es requerido"
        if not password:
            error="Password requerida"
        elif c.fetchone() is not None:
            error="Usuario {} se encuentra registrado".format(username)
        if error is None:
            c.execute(
                "insert into user (username, password) values (%s, %s)",
                (username, generate_password_hash(password))
            )
            db.commit()
            
            return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))

        
        flash(error)

    return render_template("auth/register.html")
```

Comment: Si estás comunicandote con un servidor remoto, podría ser problema con la configuración (`DATABASE_HOST`) o ambiental (comunicaciones, caida de servidores, etc.). En cualquier caso debes agregar un `try-except` para manejar apropiadamente la situación.

Comment: si, tengo un problema porque cuando inicializo la base de datos desde el teminal ejecuta bien pero, no me figura la base de datos en los schemas de workbenc, yo borre la base de datos que viene por defecto tiene algo que ver ?

Comment: donde deberia incluir el try-except??

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema Lo logro solucionar?